# How can i call a method or function in UIView from another Class called SecondViewController.swift in ios Swift

Tags: ios, swift, methods, alert

I have a MapInfoWindow in my marker which comes from a .xib file with a title and a button on it.That means that i have a UIView from my class:

```
    class MapInfoWindow: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: String!
    @IBOutlet weak var actionButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction var didTapButton (sender: Any) {

        print(button taped)
    }


    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "nib file name", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(nil, options: nil)[0] as UIView
    }

}
```

Now i wont inside my button to call the method of the actionsheet alert which is in another viewController:

```
 class FindUsViewController: UIViewController  {

    func showAlert() {

       let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Please Select an Option", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Approve", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Approve button")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Edit button")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive , handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Delete button")
    }))

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .cancel, handler:{ (UIAlertAction)in
        print("User click Dismiss button")
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
        print("completion block")
    })
}
}
```

After some research the best i found was this but notworking:

```
@IBAction var didTapButton (sender: Any) {

FindUsViewController().showAlert()

    print(button taped)
}
```

In debugging says that there is a problem in  which i didn't understood very well

Comment: `FindUsViewController()` is an no-go. You (almost) never instantiate view controllers on your own. And certainly not this way. Extract that method into a utility class / func.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **delegate** for this, try it out

```
public protocol nonPaidDelegate:  class {
    func showAlertView()
}
class MapInfoWindow: UIView {
    open var delegate:nonPaidDelegate?
    @IBAction var didTapButton (sender: Any) {

        print(button taped)
self.delegate?.showAlertView()
    }

}
```

Next go to viewcontroller

```
class FindUsViewController: UIViewController,nonPaidDelegate  {

 func showAlertView() {
        self. showAlert()

    }
}
```

and dont forget to set delegate to your viewcontroller class .(at the place of showing map view window)

```
your map window view object.delegate = self
```

Comment: You mean MapInfoWindow.delegate = self to the FindUsViewController ?

Comment: It  worked :) but inside func showAlertView() {....
 i put the method let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", ....... as in my first post..Thanks very much for the help

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help..have a great day

Answer (score 2):

You are creating an IBOutlet and not an IBAction. When dragging from the XIB to the swift file, make sure you change the type of outlet you are creating to an Action and not an Outlet.

The outlet is just a reference to the object.

[image]

Comment: The wrong is mine..it is an Action..I wrote it by mistake

Comment: Your code is very incomplete. how do you instantiate MapInfoWindow? WHy are you not initializing FindUsViewController correctly? your IBAction is still missing the func keyword, etc.. etc...

Comment: I would recommend going through a few tutorials on https://www.raywenderlich.com/ to get yourself situated with the code

Comment: in FindUsViewcontroller i have the var infoWindow: MapInfoWindow() but i think this is for calling the MapInfoWindow in the FindUsViewCotroller not to call the alert